# How to create a dialoge message that transfer user to another window

Tags: java, android, window

Can some one give an example of how I can use a window which can transfer user to another window.

for example I want to give  the user a suggestion and if he press ok he will be transfer  to the application manager setting (specifically to the settings of specific app so he can change it), ho can I do that?

thank you

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645107/android-intent-in-dialog-box

Answer (score 0):

Use JOptionPane. For example:

```
int option = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Prepare for redirecting");
if(option==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->{
    new MyAnotherWindow().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```